# Can't click on customised checkbox on Chrome and IE11

Tags: java, google-chrome, internet-explorer, selenium-webdriver, automated-tests

I have to click on customised checkbox, it's inside a div like the code following:

```html
<div class="checkbox input-group">
  <input id="checkboxH" class="checkboxClass" type="checkbox" name="checkboxH">
  <label class="required ng-scope" for="checkboxH">
    Text of checkbox
  </label>
</div>
```

I use label as element to be clicked, and it works on FF as code below

```
webDriver.findElement(By.xpath("//label[@for='checkboxH']")).click();
```

but it doesn't work on Chrome (latest version) and IE11, the error is:

> org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: unknown error: Element is not clickable at point (634, 498). Other element would receive the click:

Note that the checkbox is not visible on the screen, it has to be scrolled into view. But with the same code, it works with FF. FF can click on checkbox even when it is not in the view.

I tried another way, like this:

```
WebElement a = webDriver.findElement(By.xpath("//label[@for='checkboxH']"));
a.sendKeys(Keys.ENTER);
a.click();
```

And it also works with FF, but not Chrome and IE. It seems, selenium with FF automatically scrolls element into view and performs click on it

I am stuck here with Chrome and IE. Any help much appreciated. Thanks

**EDIT**

Apparently, I fixed issue with IE by setting this capability, and it works for IE:

```
capability.setCapability("nativeEvents", false);
```

With Chrome, I don't know which capacities could fix this issue

Comment: Looking at just the html it should work on chrome as well. What is the CSS / JavaScript doing to this checkbox? Note that for chrome driver if the label element's center overlaps some other element (with higher z-index), then you will get this error. Since in this case it tries to click the label (it clicks at the centre) but the element on top of it would receive the click

Comment: @AzureMinotaur: I also thought that should be no problem with Chrome, but this customised checkbox is tricky. About the CSS/Javascript, when the form is submitted without ticking this checkbox, then it will be marked red and the validation message shown up. So right now, I am still stuck at this thing with Chrome

Comment: When you try to click on the label, I think the click would be received by the outer enclosing div, no? That would explain the error. Can you issue click on the outer div instead of the label inside? You can run some JavaScript to attach the same click handler for the outer div as the inner label. And/ Or to make sure, can you temporarily clone the label from inside the div to its outside and see if chrome works then?

Comment: Oh and can you post the full error? It will tell you which other element would receive the click after the colon in "Other element would receive the click:". I suspect it is the outer div

Comment: @AzureMinotaur I found a workaround, I commented. Thanks a lot for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have a work around: I use Actions to move to element, then I use sleep for 2 second, then it works.